# Build error after upgrading from Xcode 6 to Xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode, build, upgrade

My project was successfully building and archiving when i used to Xcode 6.4. But, because of project specs, i upgrade my Xcode to 7.1. After upgrading, i got some build errors like:

> clang: error: unknown argument: '-finalize' 
>  clang: error:
>   unknown argument: '-prefinalized-library' 
>  clang: error: unknown
>   argument: '-finalized-product'

These were the members of "Other Linker Flags" and i remove them from the list (only from Release List). I am not sure whether it is correct or not.

Then, i am able to build when **Build Configuration** of **Scheme** was **Debug**. But, if it **Release**, i can not build and gives that error:

> clang: error: no such file or directory:
>   '.../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sample-ftkjbpybhvbkdbfhuublkrbfuddf/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/sample/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos//sample.app/sample'

I searched over internet and forums, and find nothing.

Thanks in advance & regards..

Comment: any update?? i am also facing same Issue

Answer (score 0):

Go to XCODE ->preference ->location in that [image]

change this tool option to XCode 7.0 ,may be it will give you the error.

Comment: I try with 7.0.1 but, unfortunately, it doesn't work.